# C# Deserialize weirdly formatted XML

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I spend the last day reading all the popular posts on XML deseralization on here, and while I have no problems with the sample files, I can't apply it to my particular file here (granted, maybe the format is fine and I'm just too unexperienced):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
    <gesmes:Sender>
        <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
    </gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time='2018-03-20'>
            <Cube currency='USD' rate='1.2276'/>
            <Cube currency='JPY' rate='130.72'/>
            <Cube currency='BGN' rate='1.9558'/>
            <Cube currency='CZK' rate='25.423'/>
            <Cube currency='DKK' rate='7.4485'/>
            <Cube currency='GBP' rate='0.87715'/>
            <Cube currency='HUF' rate='311.13'/>
            <Cube currency='PLN' rate='4.2277'/>
            <Cube currency='RON' rate='4.6663'/>
            <Cube currency='SEK' rate='10.0563'/>
            <Cube currency='CHF' rate='1.1721'/>
            <Cube currency='ISK' rate='122.50'/>
            <Cube currency='NOK' rate='9.4863'/>
            <Cube currency='HRK' rate='7.4423'/>
            <Cube currency='RUB' rate='70.8466'/>
            <Cube currency='TRY' rate='4.8238'/>
            <Cube currency='AUD' rate='1.5934'/>
            <Cube currency='BRL' rate='4.0410'/>
            <Cube currency='CAD' rate='1.6040'/>
            <Cube currency='CNY' rate='7.7744'/>
            <Cube currency='HKD' rate='9.6295'/>
            <Cube currency='IDR' rate='16893.01'/>
            <Cube currency='ILS' rate='4.2741'/>
            <Cube currency='INR' rate='80.0370'/>
            <Cube currency='KRW' rate='1314.93'/>
            <Cube currency='MXN' rate='23.0086'/>
            <Cube currency='MYR' rate='4.8091'/>
            <Cube currency='NZD' rate='1.7039'/>
            <Cube currency='PHP' rate='63.926'/>
            <Cube currency='SGD' rate='1.6174'/>
            <Cube currency='THB' rate='38.301'/>
            <Cube currency='ZAR' rate='14.6788'/>
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

I want to get a list of the innermost cube nodes to access the currency values.
2 things that bug me: 1. There are 3 levels of cubes, all with the same name, 2. the namespace of the Soap Envelope is not applied to the cubes themselves.

I tried the XDocument route and supplied the namespace but the yielded list only contains null items:

```
string currencies;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
                currencies = client.DownloadString("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");
}

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(currencies));
XNamespace soap = XNamespace.Get("http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01");
```

All the examplies I found put a heavy emphasis on supplying the namespace so I suspect the problem is there. I didn't need deserialization in 3 years so I'm pretty rusty on the subject, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: [This site](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) does a pretty good job of converting XML into C# objects. Just paste in your XML code and click the convert button.

Comment: @Icemanind: The website you have provided certainly can save you some work if you know how to use `XmlSerializer`. However, for this particular problem the generated classes do not work because there are three different types of `Cube` elements with different content and the generator only generates one `Cube` class based on the innermost `Cube` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is perhaps related to the use of a default namespace specified by `xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref"`? The `Cube` elements are in this namespace and you need to specify that when you query the XML:

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var ns = (XNamespace) "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref";
var currencies = xDocument
    .Root
    .Element(ns + "Cube")
    .Element(ns + "Cube")
    .Elements(ns + "Cube")
    .Select(xElement => new
    {
        Currency = (string) xElement.Attribute("currency"),
        Rate = (decimal) xElement.Attribute("rate")
    })
    .ToList();
```

This will create a list of currencies with rates. I have used an anonymous type but you can use your own type instead.

Comment: Love you, man! I really couldn't figure it out (of course, now it seems obvious). I was not aware that you can jus go through multiple node levels like that. Everytime amazing how powerful a language C# is. Many thanks!